# Lotus notes script collect documents from a view with categorized column with formula

Tags: lotus-notes

using Lotus Notes script,
is there a method to collect documents from a view with the first 3 columns categorized and with formula ?

For example:

First Column formula:  `@year(date_created)`

Second Column formula: `@month(date_created)`

Third column formula: `@day(date_created)`

and i want to collect all documents created today.

I try to do this:

```
array(1)=@year(Date)
array(2)=@month(Date)
array(3)=@day(Date)
set collection=view.getalldocumentsbykey(array(),true)
```

but the collection do not populates. 
So i try to change the code to:

```
array(1)=@year(Date)
array(2)=@month(Date)
array(3)=@day(Date)
Set ViewEntryCollection=view.GetAllEntriesByKey(array(),true)
```

but it do not work. i try to remove the categorization from all columns but nothing has chenaged.

There is a method in LotusScript to obtain this ?
Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that types of values in array are the same as types of values in columns. In your case you must use the array of integer. Also columns in view must be categorized or sorted.

```vb
Dim array(2) As Integer

array(0) = Year(Date)
array(1) = Month(Date)
array(2) = Day(Date)

Set collection = view.GetAllDocumentsByKey(array, True)
```